# In Checkstyle, is it possible to warn at one value and error at another?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'd like to configure checkstyle to have 2 levels of validation for certain rules.  For example, for the "Maximum Line Length" rule, I'd like to have a severity of `warn` if the line length exceeds 120 characters, but escalate to a severity of `error` if the line length exceeds 160 characters.

How can this be done?

Comment: I'd guess you need two separate rule declarations.

Comment: Yep, found that accidentally as I was clicking around in eclispe-cs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer at the same time Sean commented.  Just add a 2nd declaration.  Forgot you could do that.  In Eclipse, using eclipse-cs, you can just `Add...->` a module several times and configure each of them separately.